# Generating Failure / Suspension data from Weibull Distribution

Tags: maximum-likelihood, survival, reliability, weibull-distribution

I've been trying to make some synthetic failure data in MATLAB and I'm coming across an issue when I try to refit the Weibull distribution from my synthetic data.

For example, assuming a Weibull distribution with scale 35 and shape 5:

```
trial_vals = [10 20 30 40 50];
wbl_dist = wblcdf(trial_vals,35,5);

fail = [];
suspend = [];

for i=1:length(trial_vals)
    prob_of_fail = rand(1);
    if prob_of_fail >= (1-wbl_dist(i))
        fail(end+1) = trial_vals(i);
    else
        suspend(end+1) = trial_vals(i);
    end
end
```

So what's happening here is I'm testing to see whether a suspension or failure occurred for each trial value. What may come out is something like:

```
suspend = [10 20];
fail = [30 40 50];
```

I use the mle function to fit a weibull distribution to the data:

```
pdf_func = @(x,a,b) wblpdf(x,a,b);
cdf_func = @(x,a,b) wblcdf(x,a,b);
x0 = [35 5];
[opt_parm] = mle([suspend fail],'pdf',pdf_func,'cdf',cdf_func,'start',x0,'censoring',[suspend.*0+1 fail.*0],'alpha',0.1);
```

where `x0` is some initialisation.

However, in this example, my mle parameters are 43.43 and 5.74; these are way off 35 and 5. With more data points, the accuracy doesn't seem to improve.

Am I generating my synthetic suspension/failure data points incorrectly? How do I rectify this issue?

Many thanks

[edit] Confusingly, if I set pdf_func = @(x,a,b) wbl**c**df(x,a,b);, the generated fit is comparable to the original wbl parameters, but this will not follow the generated Kaplan-Meier curve (nor does it agree with the definition of the Likelihood function i.e.

$L = \prod^R_{i=1} f(F_i;\hat\theta) \cdot \prod^M_{j=1}(1-F(S_j;\hat\theta))$ where $f$ is the PDF and $F$ is the CDF.

[edit2] To account for the fact that 5 trial values is a small sample set, more can be generated using

```
samples 1000;
   samples_per_trialvals = floor(samples/length(trial_vals));
   trialvals_rand = [];

   for i=1:length(trial_vals)
        trialvals_rand = [trialvals_rand (trial_vals(i) + rand(1,samples_per_trialvals).*(trial_vals(i)/10))];
    end
```

This adds a 10% jitter to each value.

Comment: You are using 5 simulated values. You should be surprised the estimates are as precise as they are. To see why, replicate this process 1,000 times and use the MLEs to superimpose estimated density curves over the actual density curve. The long tailed distribution of the Weibull reduces the influence of skewed observations to the point that the dissimilarities of alternate parameterizations are too small to be seen as different.

Comment: I've actually tried this (I used an example with 5 values just to make my example code simple) and it converges on a completely different solution. Just to be succinct, if I use the `ecf` function to generate a Kaplan-Meier curve, `mle` converges to what the K-M looks like. However, this is not what the original weibull parameters are. If I change the pdf function `pdf_func` to that of a CDF, it converges to the original weibull parameters, but no longer resembles the K-M curve. I'm not an expert in Survival analysis (hopefully that's evident) so it's possible there's a rudimentary error. TY

Comment: Those are completely different values. The PDF, CDF, hazard, and the survival function have a functional 1-1 correspondence, but they're never equal.

Comment: Exactly, that's why it's curious that using one replicates the original parameters exactly, whilst the other replicates the K-M curve.